# how to download a pcl data?

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, pcl, mesh, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone, I want to save pcl data , the purpose is to use it to create a mesh file on which I can work on in a CAD software. Is there some existing package that can help me with it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392991/how-to-download-a-pcl-data?/) by [adiManav](https://answers.ros.org/users/61179/adimanav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @adiManav

Point Cloud is independent of ROS so you can achieve this without using ROS: https://point.cloud/

If you would like to use ROS, I suggest to start here: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview

Then go over this wonderful tutorials from `methylDragon`, easy to follow:
https://github.com/methylDragon/pcl-ros-tutorial/blob/master/PCL%20Reference%20with%20ROS.md

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0